# Uploading php-mysql website from Wamp server to godaddy

Tags: php, mysql

I have build a php-mysql website on localhost wampserver having many other folders (alias, apps, bin, lang, logs, etc. etc.) along with my website folder. While moving them to live server, what all folders should be moved to 'httpdoc' folder of godaddy. Also, what files need to be changed among them (like config file) ?

Thanks.

Comment: You have to copy all the files and folders of **your project**. also have to change path in your config files. and also change database details. **Don't copy wamp folder.**

Comment: if not to late, NEVER, host at godaddy.

Comment: So , you mean only my project folder (Say XYZ) lying inside www folder ? ryte? and other than that config file only ? what about php.ini files and other files ?

Comment: no need to upload `.ini` file.. godaddy server has that file..

Comment: ok...and config.inc file to be placed in which folder of godaddy ? Is it httpdoc folder or root directory ?

Comment: don't upload wamp server's config file.. upload only your project's config files

Comment: There is one config.inc file I could find in apps>>phpmyadmin4.1.14 folder hving localhost , id and password details. So, is this the file need to upload ? Is there any other file also ?

Comment: Apologies for the questions but I m hosting a website for the first time and I am facing internal server error 500

Comment: can you please post your project structure?

Comment: Inside www folder  , I have my project folder xyz. In xyz, I have only my project related php files. One file is a connection file  which I have modified accordingly having live server and db details.

Comment: use file manager for uploading website these are the steps when you log in to your account To Upload Files Using the File Manager. Next to the hosting account you want to use, click Manage. If an option window displays, select the directory you want to open, and then click Go. Navigate to the directory where you want to upload the file   tis is the tutorial https://in.godaddy.com/help/upload-files-3239

Comment: Thanks..but my issue is different..I want to know what files I need to upload (like config.inc, htaccess) other than my project folder. And what changes needed in those files.

Comment: Thanks guys for your suggestions. I called godaddy support and they added a webconfig file to show the actual errors. Issue is resolved now.